# Standardized random variables for two stores with differing sales

Tags: random-variables

> Mr. Norton owns two appliance stores. In store 1 the number of TV sets sold by a sales person is, on average, 13 per week with a standard deviation of ﬁve. In store 2 the number of TV sets sold by a salesperson is, on average, seven with a standard deviation of four. Mr. Norton has a position open for a person to sell TV sets. There are two applicants. Mr. Norton asked one of them to work in store 1 and the other in store 2, each for one week. The salesperson in store 1 sold 10 sets, and the salesperson in store 2 sold six sets. Based on this information, which person should Mr. Norton hire?

I know that for this problem we're supposed to use standardized random variables, but I'm not sure how I'm supposed to use it. Are there two standardized random variables, one for store 1 and one for store 2? Is this problem asking to compare expected values? What first steps should I be taking for this problem?

Comment: That was a title for a previous question I was planning to ask but figured out before I posted it. I totally forgot to change the title for this new question, just fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applicant 1 is $\frac{10 - 13}{5} = -0.6$ standard deviations above the mean in store 1, while applicant 2 is $\frac{6-7}{4} = -0.25$ standard deviations above the mean in store 2. Which is better?